# combination of (GWT & boot strap) or (JSP & Boot strap) which is better?

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, gwt

I worked on GWT in past with normal HTML editor. Now i am trying to work with bootstrap. but whether is it possible to combine GWT knowledge with boot strap or else i should go through JSP & boot strap? which combination is better to make my work easy?

Answer (score 1):

As you say , you have knowledge in GWT it can be very well used to integrate it with Bootstrap.

AFAIK,  there are two librarys for  Twitter Bootstrap integration in GWT. There is [GWT-Bootstrap](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap) and [GwtBootstrap3](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3). And this answer [GWT-Bootstrap vs. GwtBootstrap3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836186/gwt-bootstrap-vs-gwtbootstrap3)  would help you choose the one which you need.

And here is [live demo](https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/) for gwtbootstrap3. Have a look at their CSS and js components integrated with bootstrap.

The second part is [jsp + bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230748/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-with-jsp) , choosing the stack is truly based on your requirements and exposure to the technologies. I have worked jsp and bootstrap , jsp is merely an html with some additional options for dyanmic content. so it wont very tough to learn.

**See also:**

- [Why is gwt-bootstrap necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528973/why-is-gwt-bootstrap-necessary)